# MS Word inserting fields as static text

Tags: microsoft-word, office365

I'm experiencing a really weird issue with Word.

Whenever I try to insert an object (such as a bibliography or in-text citation), Word inserts it as static text (as opposed to an field containing text). This is extremely annoying, as it makes it impossible to (for example) specify what pages I'm quoting in a citation.

Does anybody know how to fix this? It was working a couple days ago, and then randomly stopped working.

Maybe it is because the file was converted from a .doc? I don't know why it would do anything (the file is currently in .docx), but it's worth mentioning.

Before people vote-to-close, I am aware that [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1709766/citations-as-text-not-object-word) exists. However, it has been a year since that was posted, with no responses.

Comment: Just this document, or any document?

Comment: @CharlesKenyon I've run some tests on other documents, and the problem is only with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a blank paragraph at the end of the document. Then copy everything except that last paragraph in a new do?cument. Save that document. Same problem?